# Using 'tr' to print repeated new lines to single new line?

Tags: bash

I have a list of words which I have sorted using the sort command and then printed all the duplicates using `uniq -D`. The output file `foo.txt` is as follows:

```
always  
always  
bat  
bat  
boot  
boot  
boot  
hi  
hi
```

I was then attempting to use the following command in a script to read the file with the `tr` command.

It's not quite working, and the output looks the same as above.

This is what I have so far:

```
 cat foo.txt | tr -s '\n'
```

The output, however, appears the same. My goal is for the output to be:

```
always always  
bat bat  
boot boot boot  
hi hi
```

Comment: `tr -d` squeezes together multiple occurrences of the same *character*, not the same line. You need something more complicated for this.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk`:

```
awk '{c=(($0!=p)?"\n":" "); printf c $0} {p=$0}' file
```

- c is the character to print before any word.
- p is the previous word.
- if previous word is different, set c as newline or else as space.

it prints newline at the beginning and no newline at end, so we can add a few more:

```
awk '{c=(($0!=p)?"\n":" "); p=$0} NR==1{printf $0;next} {printf c $0}
     END {printf "\n"}' file
```

---

another solution, you could run `uniq -c file` instead of `-D` which prints

```
  2 always
  2 bat
  3 boot
  2 hi
```

and then print the word for the times the first field says:

```
uniq -c file | awk '{for (i=1;i<$1;i++) printf $2 " "; print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate each group by a newline with uniq.

After that sed take this newline as field separator.

```
uniq --all-repeated=separate infile | sed ':A;$bB;/\n$/!{N;bA};:B;s/\n/ /g'
```